# how to set up a core data relationship between 2 classes with 2 different tableviews

Tags: swift, core-data, attributes, relationship

In my swift code I have one class for cities and one class for states. States can have many cities but a city can only have 1 state. I don't know if I set up my core data attributes correctly especially the inverse part. I know how to change it to one to many on the propties panel. I am just wondering if I am missing anything to do this. When the user selects a States it will go to a new class where the user can saves cities to only that specific state.

[image: imageOfCoreData]

Comment: That looks correct but don’t forget to set the type of relationship and deletion rule in the panel to the right (Cmd-Opt-0)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this type of things in my project, but I didn't understand your question clearly eventhough on my perspective I can say that like what I have done in my project

State entity:-

Attribute:-
stateN: String

Relationship:-
city: To-Many relationship (Destination: City, Inverse: state)

City entity:-

Attribute:-
cityN: String

Relationship:-
state: To-One relationship (Destination: State, Inverse: city)

and now if you want to selects a state and wants to save a city to that specific state.Create a new instance of **City** then Set the **cityN** attribute for new city.Set the **state** relationship of the new city to the selected state.

```
let context = persistentContainer.viewContext

// Create a new state
let state = State(context: context)
state.stateN = "Kerala"

// Create a new city
let city = City(context: context)
city.cityN = "Calicut"

// Associate the city with the state
city.state = state

// Save the changes
do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    print("Error saving context: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: When you say create a new instance of city do you mean entity or attribute. Your last paragraph describes what I am trying to do.

Comment: I meant creating a new instance of the **City** entity in Core Data.

Comment: you mean a attribute

Comment: just try my answer I have written everything in that. this is the exact way like I have coded for my app @sillymilly

Comment: I am getting the error of   let context = persistentContainer.viewContext Cannot find 'persistentContainer' in scope

Comment: did you import coredata into your ViewController and your Project? its actually an property of **NSPersistentContainer** class that having coredata Stack . did you have this class in your appDelegate?